# SwipeRefreshLayout is filling parent in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to use a `SwipeToRefreshLayout` to update some information inside a marker. Although I use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to keep the content size, for some reason it always fills the parent, leaving a huge space below the information content. What am I doing wrong?

By the way, if I don't have the `SwipeRefreshLayout` , and use only the `ScrollView`, that empty space doesn't appear.

Here is my XML code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/svMarker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/svMarkerInfo">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/llMarkerInfo">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Thank you for your answers!

I leave also the image of how is being showed using the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Behind the marker information there is a map:

[image: Image showing the marker info using the SwipeRefreshLayout]

If I dont use `SwipeRefreshLayout`, the marker information is shown the next way, which visually is what I am looking for. but I'm missing the SwipeToRefresh update:

[image: Image showing the marker info without using SwipeRefreshLayout]

Comment: You haven't added any elements inside Linear Layout  na? Try adding some TextView or something so that it can make some height.

Comment: i simplified it. Will add an image so you can see what does it have inside. But, as I said, it is shown perfectly if I take away the SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: Can't you use recycle view instead of scrollview and Linear layout? so that you can set an adapter for the same, to create this layout.

Comment: I can use anything that is necessary to solve the problem. This is why im asking :)  if you have a solution, post it

Comment: User Relative layout / Linear Layout as parent layout. Inside the Layout user SwipeLayout and other components such as textviews, buttons. And inside the swipe layout use Recyclerview.

Comment: @ragu-swaminathan how do I use the Recyclerview? By the way, and just in case, I dont need a listview, I need a scrollview

Comment: The information and the flag should be at the bottom of the screen. isn't it? And is all the content is inside the linear layout ?

Comment: @DiieBarcia are you using the custom listview to show the items you displayed in the image [ the one with alarm like symbol and bus  icons ]

Comment: @FAЯAƸ acually, all the information of the marker should be at the botton (from Parada to the flag), and over it the map should be seen.

Comment: @Ragu Swaminathan Actually not. They are not a listView, they are just components added dynamically

Comment: @DiieBarcia Could you post your complete layout.xml ?

Comment: @FAЯAƸ yeah, thats quite what I want to do. I will add an image to the quiestion with how I want it to be shown.
And no, I dont think is a good idea to post the complete xml. It's really long and messy. that is the only part I am having problems

Comment: @DiieBarcia Did u try using weights in LinearLayout ?

Comment: actually for what purpose you are using swipe refresh layout ? @DiieBarcia

Comment: @Ragu Swaminathan the user scrolls down over the marker information, and the time shown is updated

Comment: @FAЯAƸ I tried, not working neither

Comment: Use fill_parent for both SwipeRefreshLayout and ScrollView height and add filleViewPort=true for ScrollView and try.

Comment: @Surender Kumar thanks, but didn't work either

Comment: so there will be always 2 marker constantly shown there . ?

Comment: @Ragu Swaminathan if you refer to marker's information, there are plenty of markers in the map, but their information is shown one at a time. If you refer to the ítems inside the marker information (145 and 104), then no, there can be more or less ítems inside.

Comment: for better understanding can you share your XML file .?

Comment: @Ragu Swaminathan as I say before, you wont understand better wuth my XML file. It has many more things that will confuse you. Anyways, I found a solution. Will post it now. Thanks any way :)

Comment: ok. great..!! have a good day..

Answer (score 0):

The `SwipeRefreshLayout` will disabled while dragging a map by using a listener and the refresh will only take place if you swipe down on the second half ( i.e. the layout below map). To get map drag events, we need to do some workaround because there is no direct support from Google and this library [MapStateListener](https://github.com/madsbf/MapStateListener) has done that. Just paste these three classes `MapStateListener.java`, `TouchableMapFragment.java`, `TouchableWrapper.java` into your project.

Here is a working example.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private View  secondHalf;
    private TouchableMapFragment mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.svMarker);
        secondHalf = findViewById(R.id.secondHalf);

        setUpMap();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh()
            {
                // A thread to keep RefreshLayout busy for 5 seconds
                if(!swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
                    new LoadImagesTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setUpMap()
    {
        try
        {
            if (mMap == null)
            {
                mMap = ((TouchableMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.firstHalf));
                mMap.getMapAsync(this);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        new MapStateListener(googleMap, mMap, this)
        {
            @Override
            public void onMapTouched()
            {
                // Map touched
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapReleased() {
                // Map released
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapUnsettled() {
                // Map unsettled
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapSettled() {
                // Map settled
            }
        };
    }

    private class LoadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout android:id="@+id/svMarker"
                                              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/firstHalf"
            android:name="com.esealed.watermeterclient.TouchableMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/secondHalf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

               <!-- Other views comes here -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: thanks. The problem with that is that if I scroll down over the map, the SwipeRefreshLayout will appear too, and that goes against the Google Design specification (https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/swipe-to-refresh.html#swipe-to-refresh-swipe-to-refresh)
if you take away the SwipeRefreshLayout, is basically what I'm doing in my code :)

Comment: @DiieBarcia `SwipeRefreshLayout` should only work when you drag on the second half... not on the first half ( MAP ) and refresh should appear from the top?

Comment: but the 'loading icon' will apear on the top of the screen.. and if the user is swipping over the marker info, will confuse him cause the 'loading icon' won't appear inside the marker information

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really apreciate your effort, but I found a way to solve my problem. I cant understand why using wrap_content directly doesn't solve the problem... Will post my answer now

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could figure out was defining the `SwipeRefreshLayout` size dinamically. No need to change my XML file.

On my MapActivity.class, where I manage the marker's info, every time I show a new marker information, I call the next method:

```
LinearLayout llMarkerInfo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMarkerInfo);
SwipeRefreshLayout svMarker = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.svMarker);

//First i register to the listener so I can get the measured size of the marker information's layout
ViewTreeObserver vto = llMarkerInfo.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override        
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        //I get the measured width and height of the marker information's layout
        int width = llMarkerInfo.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = llMarkerInfo.getMeasuredHeight();

        //Set that size to the SwipeToRefresh layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams svParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
        svMarker.setLayoutParams(svParams);

        //Unregister the listener so is not called many times
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
            llMarkerInfo.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        else
            llMarkerInfo.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
     }
});
```

This way, I define exactly the size my marker information's layout has, to my `SwipeRefreshLayout`, dinamically.

Image with the final result (expected = reality):
[image: Image with the final result]